# How to inherit outer UI components in vue/nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue, my project uses Vue2, Nuxt and Vuetify.

I would like to make a base `.vue` component, and several components derived from the base.

For example, this is my base dailog `MyDialog.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="isShowDialog" persistent>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title> My Base Dialog </v-card-title>

      <!-- inherited UI logic goes here -->

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="closeDialog"> Close </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isShowDialog: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.isShowDialog = false
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

For the derived components, I would like to make something like `ImageDialog.vue`, `LoginFormDialog.vue`, `ComplexDialog.vue`, each have it's own child UI and logic besides the base `MyDialog.vue`.

For example, could I achieve something like this:

```html
<MyDialog>
    <div>
        <span>This is an image</span>
        <img src="...">
    </div>
</MyDialog>
```

Anywhere that I should start? Or any document I could reference?

Comment: Are you using vue2 or vue3?

Comment: @DengSihan since Vuetify just went live for Vue3, I suppose OP is using Vue2. Otherwise, it would probably have been tagged like that + probably used some Composition API.

Comment: @DengSihan I'm using vue2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic components, you could use a simple nesting of each component inside of the other.

If you want more flexibility + reusability, you can use slots: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

Basic named slots are quite powerful, but scoped slots are even better. Meanwhile, be careful because it's a more advanced pattern.

Here is somebody well known in the Vue community, if you are looking for a bigger course on the subject: https://michaelnthiessen.com/#courses

Comment: Thanks. Slots are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can import component into another component.
Please refer below reference:
https://flaviocopes.com/vue-import-component/